# Creating tabs with listviews dynamically in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, tabs, jquery-mobile-listview

I am trying to create tabs with listviews in JQM dynamically on a button click. Currently, I use JS array that contains sample data which will finally be populated via ajax. After research, it seems that I should trigger either trigger("create") or trigger ("refresh"), but apparently, I don't do it correctly. Here's the code:

**HTML:**

`<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>navbar demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/nav.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <button onclick="fillCategories()">Fill</button>
         <div id = "decisions" > </div>
     </body>
    </html>`

**Javascript:**

```
function fillCategories() {
var navElements =   [{"category_sublist_id":"1","category_sublist_name":"Europe"},
                    {"category_sublist_id":"2","category_sublist_name":"Asia"},
                    {"category_sublist_id":"3","category_sublist_name":"Americas"}];
var categoriesTabs = $('<div id="categories">')
                        .attr("data-role","tabs")
                        .appendTo("#decisions");
var navBar = $("<div>").attr("id","categoriesNames")
                        .attr("data-role","navbar")
                        .appendTo("#categories");
var listElements =  [{"sublist_row_id":"1","category_sublist_id":"1","sublist_name":"Great Britain"},
                    {"sublist_row_id":"2","category_sublist_id":"1","sublist_name":"Sweden"},
                    {"sublist_row_id":"3","category_sublist_id":"1","sublist_name":"France"},
                    {"sublist_row_id":"4","category_sublist_id":"1","sublist_name":"Germany"}];

$("#categoriesNames").append($("<ul>").attr("id","categoriesUl"));
$(navElements).each(function(){
        $("#categoriesUl").append($("<li>")
            .attr("value", this.category_sublist_id)
            .append($("<a>")
                .attr("href", "#sublist"+this.category_sublist_id)
                .attr("data-theme","a")
                .attr("data-ajax","false")
                .text(this.category_sublist_name)));
});

$("#categories").append(navBar).trigger("create");
categorySublistView("categories", "sublist2", listElements);}

function categorySublistView(elementId, listLink, listData) {
var listId = listLink+"id";
var tab = $("<div>").attr("id",listLink)
                    .addClass("ui-content")
                    .appendTo("#"+elementId);
var list = $("<ul>").attr("data-role","listview")
                    .attr("data-inset","true")
                    .attr("data-icon","false")
                    .attr("id", listId)
                    .appendTo("#"+listLink);
$(listData).each(function(){
    var li = $("<li/>")
        .attr("value",this.sublist_row_id)
        .appendTo("#"+listId);
    var link =$("<a>")
        .attr("href", "#")
        .text(this.sublist_name)
        .appendTo(li);
});
if ( $('#'+listId).hasClass('ui-listview')) {
    $('#'+listId).listview('refresh');
 }
else {
    $('#'+listId).trigger('create');
 }}
```

**edit:**
My initial intention was to draw 3 tabs in the navbar which are listviews, which are visible on tab clicks

Comment: Here is your code running in jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/qky8coxh/

With respect to that, can you explain further what you are trying to achieve and what is not working as you expected?

Comment: Thanks for the snippet! There are several problems with my implementation: 1. When you click on the "fill" button, you have the "navbar" drawn correctly, but the inner tab is visible immediately (not intended) 2. When you click on the "fill" button several times - you have the "listview" which is formatted well, but pops up in unexpected places.

Comment: Is this closer to what you wanted ...

http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/qky8coxh/2/